# Show that $G$ contains two adjacent vertices $u$ and $v$ such that $\deg u + \deg v$ is even.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a nontrivial connected graph that is not bipartite. Show that $G$
contains two adjacent vertices $u$ and $v$ such that $\deg u + \deg v$ is even.

#### Progress

I know the $\deg(u)$ and $\deg(v)$ are either both even or odd and that this is going to be true because the graph is not bipartite, but I don't really know where to go to connect those two things.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? This is beginning to be no longer partly a homework answer site.

Comment: To be honest I just need a starting point. I mean I know the deg(u) and deg(v) are either both even or odd and that this is going to be true because it is not bipartite, but I don't really know where to go to connect those two things.

Comment: This is maybe just a slightly different way of viewing Math1000's answer, but you can colour vertices using colours $0$ and $1$ by colouring vertex $v$ by $\deg(v)\bmod 2$. But since $G$ has an odd cycle, there are two adjacent vertices of the same colour...

Comment: @Casteels - that's correct. A graph is bipartite iff it is $2$-colorable iff it has no odd cycles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are no vertices $u,v$ such that $\deg u + \deg v$ is even, let $U$ be the set of even-degree vertices and $V$ the set of odd-degree vertices. Then $(U,V)$ is a bipartition of $G$.